# How do I get a user to input a document and then save that document?

Tags: sql, vb.net, document

So I'm a bit stuck with my project, I am using Visual Studio and coding in Visual Basic, I am also using Microsoft Access with SQL if that helps at all.

What I need is to allow the user to select a document from an OpenFileDialog and to then save that document to the actual program so it is there when the program is next ran.

The following code is triggered on a button press, what I have so far is...

```
    saveDocumentDialog.Filter = "Document Files|*.docx;*.doc;*.dot;*.txt;*.rtf;*.pdf;*.ppt;*.pptx;*.xls;*.xlsx"
    saveDocumentDialog.FileName = "Untitled"
    saveDocumentDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    saveDocumentDialog.ShowDialog()

    If saveDocumentDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        fullFilename = saveDocumentDialog.FileName

    End If

    Using openDocumentDialog As New SaveFileDialog

        Dim filename As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(fullFilename)
        openDocumentDialog.FileName = "Untitled"
        openDocumentDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
        openDocumentDialog.Title = "Select Save Location"
        openDocumentDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"

        If openDocumentDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Try

                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(fullFilename, openDocumentDialog.FileName)

            Catch ex As Exception

                MessageBox.Show("Could not copy the file." & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, "Error copying file.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            End Try

        End If
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: There is no problem with it, I just need to save the documents that they select in the saveDocumentDialog portion to the actual project as at the moment once you close Visual Studio the document is no longer saved and so I want that document to say in the project

Comment: What you mean by "to stay in the actual project"? When you start application again, you can reload files from the location you saved them before.

Comment: Ah okay my bad, I presumed because you don't set an actual save location for files within the projects source folder they don't reload.

Comment: It'll be a struggle to have your program write files into the Program Files folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to designate a specific folder to the program(e.g. Public Documents), and save the files there and reload them from the folder when the program restarts. You could either hard code the path, or make a setting in the program for the user to specify a folder they would prefer.